# WP Customize/Live Preview Options

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

I'm new for use Redux Framework with my theme CrazyHour. I faced a problem when I open the WP live customize preview. My theme controls hide after full page load.
I try my best like update framework, check my options array & search on internet etc. But I have not found the solution for this type of error in my theme.

Answer (score 0):

Some customizer controls are context dependent, maybe that's why your controls are being hidden. You can try changing the page. If this is not the case then please check your browser console maybe you'll get some hints or clue there.

Btw, are you referring this theme: https://themeforest.net/item/crazy-hour-event-management-wordpress-theme/19574149 ? If yes, then please contact their support team.

Comment: I'm the developer of this theme and I'm trying to diagnose this, but I can't reach to the problem.